# create a dict or list from a matrix(csv) in python using standard libraries/modules

Tags: python, csv, dictionary, matrix, multidimensional-array

I have a matrix in csv format that I'm trying to read in and create a k:v dict from, where the x/y headers are the key and value is the cell that they map to.
I'm unable to use any non-standard libraries or modules.

The csv looks like this:

```
 ,A,B,C
A,1,9,3
B,6,3,5
C,3,8,8
```

and I want the dict to look like this:

```
{AA:1,BA:9,CA:3,AB:6,BB:3,CB:5,AC:3,BC:8,CC:8}
```

what I have so far:

```
matrixDict=defaultdict(list)
with open("/path/to/substitutionMatrix.csv", "rb") as confusion_data:
    reader = csv.reader(confusion_data, dialect = csv.excel, delimiter = ',')
    headers = reader.next()
    i,j=1,1
    for row in reader:
        x=row[0]+headers[i]+(row[j])
        for y in row:
             matrixDict[x]=y
```

but this isn't working, it gives me a key with a list, instead of the cell's value that the key is supposed to map to.

Comment: you are telling it to create a list (append) instead of setting a key to a dict, the assignment should be matrixDict[x] = y, how ever the loop isnt quite right either since you are not handling the column header in the key

Comment: that's helpful (I'll edit the question to reflect the correct assignment). But I still can't figure out how to handle the column header.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
import csv
from collections import defaultdict

matrixDict=defaultdict(list)
with open("m.csv", "r") as confusion_data:
    reader = csv.reader(confusion_data, dialect = csv.excel, delimiter = ',')
    headers = reader.next()

    for row in reader:
        for i in range(1,len(headers)):
            matrixDict[headers[i]+row[0]] = row[i]

print matrixDict
```

Comment: This works great. I added in some explanation of the second `for` loop as a sanity check for myself. If any of that is wrong feel free to change. 
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import csv

matrixDict = dict()
with open('csv', 'r') as confusion_data:
    reader = csv.reader(confusion_data, dialect=csv.excel, delimiter=',')
    headers = reader.next()
    for row in reader:
        header_index = 1
        for col in row[1:]:
            key = headers[header_index] + row[0]
            matrixDict[key] = col
            header_index += 1

print matrixDict
```

For the given input as a file named "csv" it outputs

```
{'AA': '1', 'AC': '3', 'AB': '6', 'BA': '9', 'BB': '3', 'BC': '8', 'CC': '8', 'CB': '5', 'CA': '3'}
```